# Function that fulfils the equation

Tags: analysis, functions, exponential-function

Prove that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists only one $y=y(x)$ that fulfils the equation: $$3x+e^x=y+e^y$$
I am completely lost with that. What should i do?

Comment: This is an *implicit* function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x,y)=3x+e^x-y-e^y$$.

We know that in the first place for all fixed real $x$, there always exists at least a  real $y$ s.t. $f(x,y)=0$, since $y+e^y$ ranges from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. So it suffices to show that such a $y$ is unique, which is evident from the fact 
 $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial
y}(x,y)=-1-e^y<-1\ne 0$$
due to [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

For any real number $a$, the equation $a=y+e^y$, or $e^y=a-y$, has exactly one solution (think of the plots, and use the Intermediate Value Theorem and the fact that the functions are monotone).  So for each $x$, there is a unique $y(x)$ satisfying the equation.